# Want to rewrite URL through HTACCESS

Tags: .htaccess, clean-urls

I'm sure this has been asked in other forms, but I can't for the likes of me get this thing working after googling/trying for hours.

I have a bunch of URLs like this:

```
www.yoursite.com/pic_box.php?pic=$
```

What I want is that all URLs will only be avaiable with clean URLs.

```
www.yoursite.com/your-title-here
```

Can any htaccess  master help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

In your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^picbox/(.*)$ /pic_box.php?pic=$1 [NC,L]
```

Will give you the ability to rename your url like that:
www.yoursite.com/picbox/your-pic-id

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these rules to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pic_box.php?pic=$1 [L]
```